# How can I validate a field against an external 3rd party REST API

Tags: apex, validation

I'd like to validate a field in Salesforce, against some other external REST API.

I thought I could do this with triggers, but when I tried something like this:

```
trigger testvalidate on Account (before insert) {

        for (Account a : trigger.new)
        {
            ... 

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint('https://my url here ...');
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setBody(json);

            Http http = new Http();
            HttpResponse resp = http.send(req);

            ...
        }

}
```

I get an error like this:

```
estvalidate: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.CalloutException: Callout from triggers are currently not supported. Trigger.testvalidate: line 15, column 1
```

Is there a way to do validation against external services in Salesforce?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a synchronous call but, you can do an asynchronous call with the help of a future method as below.

```
trigger testvalidate on Account (before insert) {

        for (Account a : trigger.new)
        {
            AccountHelper.callWebService(a.Id);
        }

}

public with sharing class AccountHelper {

    @future(callout=true)
    public static void callWebService(Id accId){
        //Do the webservice callout here
    }
}
```

Please note there is a Limit of 10 callouts in a single context. So you have to design according to your requirement to avoid hitting the limit.